# Google sheets - Find the substring based on a column of substring

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets, I managed to return the particular substring based on the provided list of substring from a full string. But the problem is, I don't know how to apply it across the column with array formula.

This is what is did so far.
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWUIe.png)
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOB2A.png)

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!"&ARRAYFORMULA(ADDRESS(LARGE(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!A2:A,A2))*ROW(Sheet2!A2:A),1),1))&"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your current formula as an arrayformula, you can use BYROW:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!"&ARRAYFORMULA(ADDRESS(LARGE(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!A2:A,each))*ROW(Sheet2!A2:A),1),1))&""))))
```

Comment: Thx a lot martin! BYROW is the exact thing I'm looking for. Dint know google sheet formula have something similar to python lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
=byrow(A2:A,lambda(z,if(z="",,ifna(regexextract(z,textjoin("|",1,Sheet2!A2:A))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for sharing another approach(BYROW and regex)! Guess i need to explore more on regex. Btw what if the substring involved "(" symbol or any special symbol, how do i write in regex? eg. "dog (A2) - 3". Too bad i don't have enough reputation to vote this answer

Comment: you can escape the `(` with a backslash alike `\(`

Comment: i see, so to make it works in regexextract, i need to substitute the symbol by adding black slash for each of them.